# Open LDAP and Exchange synchronisation

Tags: exchange, openldap

I am currently testing some IP Phone solutions and we want to use a Central Phonebook. The Phone we currently have and are most likely want to keep, is a Grandstream GXP2130. It can access an LDAP Phone adress book, which works, on an Open LDAP. The contacts are however stored on the GAL on an Microsoft Exchange Server. Sure, the easiest solution would be to direct the phones directly to the Exchange, however the manufacturer does not support this, and i have read on the Forums of them, that some have tried and failed. So i would not want to follow in their footsteps.

So i thought it would be an idea, to have the LDAP Server, do a kind of replication with the Exchange, and then the Phones can take the information from the LDAP. I have not found any concrete Manual of how this would be done, or if it even can be done.

Another reason for the LDAP as the "man in the middle" is to 
a) have a backup for the phonebook. So should the Exchange not be working, the phones still have access to the content of the last replication.

b) Should the company buy other phones, i suppose an LDAP is something most phones can connect to, so even with different devices, nothing major would have to be changed.

However should you have other ideas, please share them with me and thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Microsoft GAL (=Active Directory Global Address List) used the Active Directory as basis to generate the offline address book content (see MS documentation [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232119(v=exchg.150).aspx): "An address list is a collection of recipient and other Active Directory objects."). So you could simply build a taskuser and point that to one Active Directory Domain controller via the LDAP Port (389) and fetch the content from there...

BUT i personally think that there is no need to start to sync anything. An Exchange object (e.g. Contact, mailbox, ...) is an element in the Active Directory and can therefore also be found via LDAP provided by your domain controller... So you could connect the Grandstream GXP2130 directly to your active directory environment (assuming that you store contacts and info's there and do not need to fetch multiple local user owned adressbooks).

To test the LDAP connection & user account you could by the way use "[Apache Directory Studio](http://directory.apache.org/studio/)". (Keep noted that you need the JDK (Java Development Kit) here and not the normal java jre!). Here is an configuration example for you:

[image]
[image]

Once it works with Apache Directory Studio you can use the active directory user on the phone and you should have what you need here.

*P.S. To have a kind of failover for the LDAP server you could build a DNS Round robin pointing it to two Domain Controller and if one is down the iPhone might switch to the one which is working. But the phones need to support that, if you can enter only one IP instead a DNS name it will not work via that way.*

Comment: Okay, that worked, thank you. At least, i can access the DC with an LDAP Browser and the Phone. However, when i try to pinpoint to the GAL:  
Configuration [.contoso.com]  
◦CN=Configuration,DC=contoso,DC=com  
◦CN=Services  ◦CN=Microsoft Exchange  
◦CN=OrganizationName  
◦CN=Address Lists Container  
◦CN=All Global Address Lists  
i can only manuever to the Organisation Name. I presume it has something to do user rights, or does it?

Comment: The GAL itself is build by AD properties, you do not need to use the GAL, you need to point to the OU where the user objects exists you wish to use in the IP phone. However this depends on your AD structure and as i do not know that one I couldn´t go further here.